# How to test the minified file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular project works well when I am building it using grunt. But when I am compiling it(minifying the javascripts and joining all of them together) I am seeing an error. How do I know what is the issue? It is too difficult debugging a minified file.

Do sugguest if someone faced a similar situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does you minifier use sourcemaps? They could be used to trace back to the original code.

Comment: use jshint before minifying, this will highlight all your errors, read this blog post: http://ionicframework.com/blog/minifying-your-source-code/

Comment: Going to the area causing the error using your browser dev tools may give you an idea where in the original file to look. Also minification errors are often caused by not adding inline annotations or not setting `$inject` properties correctly, so check through your code for those.

Comment: I am using grunt taskrunner to minify the source code. Forgive me for my ignorance but I am not sure how to identify the minifier name?

Comment: I am using jshint and it is not showing any errors. I tried debugging the code using firebug/ chrome dev tools but the code doesn't make any sense in  the minified version.

Comment: @Rhumborl: The sequence of injected properties do not affect the code as per my knowledge. The issue is how to identify the error. It can be resolved by multiple ways later. How to identify the criminal among 100's of source code files, that's the problem.

Comment: make sure you are using ngAnnotate before running minifier, that will fix dependency injections

Comment: I am already using ngmin for correcting annotations. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Sirko suggested, using source maps is a useful way to track this down.

But, when an Angular project fails on minification, the most common culprit is dependency injection.

For instance, let's say you have a controller:

```
module('test').controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.foo = 100;
});
```

The minifier will turn that into:

```
module('test').controller('TestCtrl', function(a, b) {
  a.foo = 100;
});
```

Now your injection is broken!  There are several solutions, but the most common is to pass in an array instead:

```
module('test').controller('TestCtrl', ["$scope", "$location", function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.foo = 100;
}]);
```

Another common approach to this is to add `$inject` to your function:

```
module('test').controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl);
function TestCtrl($scope, $location) {
  $scope.foo = 100;
};
TestCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$location"];
```

If you are already doing something like this, go back and double-check that everything is doing this properly.  There are ways to automate it as well.  If it is still happening, what error do you get in the console?

Comment: This is the error I get:                                        (intermediate value)(...) is not a function

....keyCode&&(f.$$apply=!1,C(a))})}}}])}(),function(){"use strict";angular.module("...

Comment: So, does that mean you are annotating your injections properly?  If so, it looks like source maps are your next best option.  You'll have to look at your `gruntfile.js` to figure out what you are using to minify, and see if that minifier supports the creation of source maps.  If it doesn't, consider switching minifiers to one that does.  They are a really useful tool for this type of thing.